# Your binstub at ./bin/rails was generated by Bundler instead of Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

I recently cloned a previous project I was working on to a new computer. I was using `RVM` but switched over to `rbenv` on my new computer. Whenever I run any `rails` command I am getting this error. Not really sure how to fix this as I am learning rails/ruby at the moment

```
Beginning in Rails 4, Rails ships with a `rails` binstub at ./bin/rails that
should be used instead of the Bundler-generated `rails` binstub.

If you are seeing this message, your binstub at ./bin/rails was generated by
Bundler instead of Rails.

You might need to regenerate your `rails` binstub locally and add it to source
control:

 rails app:update:bin           # Bear in mind this generates other binstubs
                                # too that you may or may not want (like yarn)

If you already have Rails binstubs in source control, you might be
inadvertently overwriting them during deployment by using bundle install
with the --binstubs option.

If your application was created prior to Rails 4, here's how to upgrade:

  bundle config --delete bin    # Turn off Bundler's stub generator
  rails app:update:bin          # Use the new Rails executables
  git add bin                   # Add bin/ to source control

You may need to remove bin/ from your .gitignore as well.

When you install a gem whose executable you want to use in your app,
generate it and add it to source control:

  bundle binstubs some-gem-name
  git add bin/new-executable

Traceback (most recent call last):
        4: from /Users/liondancer/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/bin/rails:23:in `<main>'
        3: from /Users/liondancer/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/bin/rails:23:in `load'
        2: from /Users/liondancer/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.1/exe/rails:10:in `<top (required)>'
        1: from /Users/liondancer/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'
/Users/liondancer/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require': cannot load such file -- rails/cli (LoadError)
        7: from /Users/liondancer/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/bin/rails:23:in `<main>'
        6: from /Users/liondancer/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/bin/rails:23:in `load'
        5: from /Users/liondancer/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.1/exe/rails:10:in `<top (required)>'
        4: from /Users/liondancer/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:156:in `require'
        3: from /Users/liondancer/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:161:in `rescue in require'
        2: from /Users/liondancer/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/rubygems.rb:211:in `try_activate'
        1: from /Users/liondancer/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1365:in `activate'
/Users/liondancer/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/specification.rb:2237:in `check_version_conflict': can't activate railties-6.0.2.2, already activated railties-6.0.3.1 (Gem::LoadError)
        8: from /Users/liondancer/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/bin/rails:23:in `<main>'
        7: from /Users/liondancer/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/bin/rails:23:in `load'
        6: from /Users/liondancer/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.1/exe/rails:10:in `<top (required)>'
        5: from /Users/liondancer/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:156:in `require'
        4: from /Users/liondancer/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:161:in `rescue in require'
        3: from /Users/liondancer/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/rubygems.rb:210:in `try_activate'
        2: from /Users/liondancer/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/rubygems.rb:217:in `rescue in try_activate'
        1: from /Users/liondancer/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1365:in `activate'
/Users/liondancer/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/specification.rb:2237:in `check_version_conflict': can't activate railties-6.0.2.2, already activated railties-6.0.3.1 (Gem::LoadError)
```

Comment: This has a pretty comprehensive list of things you can do to fix it. Did any of them work?

Comment: @tadman I am using RubyMine as my IDE and I was able to get my server running via Run/Debug button. But when I tried to clear all my records in all my tables with command line is where I saw the problem. I'm not sure where to start with this as I have no idea what a `binstub` is

Comment: Okay, but did you do any of the things it suggested? If so what happened?

Comment: A "binstub" is an entry in your Rails project `bin/` folder so you can do things like `bin/rails` and get the correct version of Rails, regardless of which other version(s) you have installed, or even if you don't have Rails globally installed.

Comment: @tadman ahh gotcha. Yes I just tried `./bin/rails s` and the error went away! I guess I was using `rbenv`'s `rails` instead of the one in the bin folder. Is there a shortcut that automatically reference the correct rails `binstub` when I am within a particular project directory?

Comment: Not really. That's what your `PATH` does. If the default (global) Rails install conflicts, you can always remove that with `gem uninstall rails`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is right there:

```
rails app:update:bin
```

Comment: Look at the last line of the error in the question: ```/Users/liondancer/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/specification.rb:2237:in `check_version_conflict': can't activate railties-6.0.2.2, already activated railties-6.0.3.1 (Gem::LoadError)```, I think OP needs to run `bundle update` and then run `rails app:update:bin`

Comment: `bundle config --delete bin` might be needed to prevent the next `bundle update` from reverting the changes made by `rails app:update:bin`